# Why i have one error. in all analogue pastebin-api npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have some issues with my code. I am currently hosting my bot on replit for testing purposes. The code seems to be broken. The error has been mentioned below.

CODE:

```js
const { connect, connection: db } = require('mongoose')
const PasteClient = require('pastebin-api').default
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9')
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest')
const { resolve } = require('path')
const { sync } = require('glob')

require('./Interaction')
require('./Event')

module.exports = class Bot extends Client {
  constructor () {
    super({
      intents: Object.values(Intents.FLAGS),
      partials: ['MESSAGE', 'REACTION'],
      allowedMentions: {
        parse: ['roles', 'users'],
        repliedUser: false
      }
    })

    this.events = new Collection()
    this.logger = require('../utils/Logger')
    this.interactions = new Collection()
    this.database = {}
    this.guildsData = require('../models/Guilds')
    this.database.guilds = new Collection()

    db.on('connected', async () =>
      this.logger.log(
                `Successfully connected to the database! (Latency: ${Math.round(await this.databasePing())}ms)`,
                { tag: 'Database' }
      )
    )

    db.on('disconnected', () => this.logger.error('Disconnected from the database!', { tag: 'Database' }))

    db.on('error', (error) =>
      this.logger.error(
                `Unable to connect to the database!\n${error.stack ? error + '\n\n' + error.stack : error}`,
                {
                  tag: 'Database'
                }
      )
    )

    db.on('reconnected', async () =>
      this.logger.log(
                `Reconnected to the database! (Latency: ${Math.round(await this.databasePing())}ms)`,
                { tag: 'Database' }
      )
    )
  }

  async getGuild ({ _id: guildId }, check) {
    if (this.database.guilds.get(guildId)) {
      return check ? this.database.guilds.get(guildId).toJSON() : this.database.guilds.get(guildId)
    } else {
      let guildData = check ? await this.guildsData.findOne({ _id: guildId }).lean() : await this.guildsData.findOne({ _id: guildId })

      if (guildData) {
        if (!check) this.database.guilds.set(guildId, guildData)
        return guildData
      } else {
        guildData = new this.guildsData({ _id: guildId })
        await guildData.save()
        this.database.guilds.set(guildId, guildData)
        return check ? guildData.toJSON() : guildData
      }
    }
  }

  /* Start database */
  async loadDatabase () {
    return connect(process.env.MONGO, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
  }

  /* Get database ping */
  async databasePing () {
    const cNano = process.hrtime()
    await db.db.command({ ping: 1 })
    const time = process.hrtime(cNano)
    return (time[0] * 1e9 + time[1]) * 1e-6
  }

  async loadPaste () {
    const paste = new PasteClient(process.env.PASTEBIN_API_KEY)
    this.paste = paste
  }

  /* Load slash commands for each guilds */
  async loadInteractions (guildId) {
    const intFile = await sync(resolve('./src/commands/**/*.js'))

    intFile.forEach((filepath) => {
      const File = require(filepath)
      if (!(File.prototype instanceof Interaction)) return

      const interaction = new File()
      interaction.client = this
      this.interactions.set(interaction.name, interaction)

      const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN)

      rest.post(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.CLIENT_ID, guildId),
        {
          body: interaction
        }
      )
    })
  }

  /* Load events */
  async loadEvents () {
    const evtFile = await sync(resolve('./src/events/**/*.js'))

    evtFile.forEach((filepath) => {
      const File = require(filepath)
      if (!(File.prototype instanceof Event)) return

      const event = new File()
      event.client = this
      this.events.set(event.name, event)
      const emitter = event.emitter ? (typeof event.emitter === 'string' ? this[event.emitter] : emitter) : this
      emitter[event.type ? 'once' : 'on'](event.name, (...args) => event.exec(...args))
    })
  }

  /* Start the bot */
  async start (token) {
    await this.loadEvents()
    await this.loadDatabase()
    await this.loadPaste()
    return super.login(token)
  }
}
```

Error:
[image: Error]

I tried more npm and the error didn't fix

Comment: If you console.log out the api key right above where you use it, is it defined?

Comment: by logic, yes. If no, it would be different

Comment: That error message is coming from [this constructor](https://github.com/Dev-CasperTheGhost/pastebin-api/blob/main/src/PasteClient.ts#L33) and implies that your API key is not defined (everything in process.env is a string, so it's not a type problem).

Comment: oh, ty, i. wanna rewrite code and put some changes

Comment: Maybe i stupid, i rewrited code for some moments and get new error..

Comment: If you can't find a solution for your new error after searching on StackOverflow and your preferred search engine, you're of course welcome to post a new question :)

Comment: Zac, i added
```js
  constructor(options, string | ClientOptions); {
    if (!options) {
      throw new TypeError(`${ERROR_PREFIX} 'options' must be type 'string' or type 'object'`);
    }

    if (typeof options === "string") {
      this.apiKey = options;
    } else {
      this.apiKey = options.apiKey;
      this.domain = options.domain ?? "pastebin.com";
    }
        }
```

and options - not defined

Comment: You don't need to add that code, that's the code from the library you're using where that error is being thrown. The code indicates that `process.env.PASTEBIN_API_KEY` is undefined. If you console.log out that variable before you try using it and it shows up correctly, then that's the wrong path to figuring out the issue.